# Python regex capture issue

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression that captures the text from a text file. The regex can ve viewed at the following URL:
https://regex101.com/r/wwEjTF/1

In my python code I would like extract the text that is matched by the regex only from all the other text in the text file. 
I have following python code for matching th regex and storing it in a variable.

```
match = re.findall(r'test\s.+\n\sdescription\s\"(.+)\"', text, re.S)
```

I am expecting all the matches to be in the match variable and returned a list.
But when I do `print (match)` I get empty list. I do not understand why it is coming up an empty list. How do i capture the matched part of the regex into the variable.
Thanks for your help. 
Just in case if there is an issue with the above url, is the regex and the sample text string:

```
test\s.+\n\sdescription\s\"(.+)\"
```

> ```
> some random text
> test 111.333.555.666
>   description "text10"
> some random text
> some random text
> test 22.44.55.66
>   description "text12"
> some random text
> some random text
> test 77.77.88.99
>   description "text13"
> some random text
> some random text
> test 14.22.55.99
>   description "text16"
> some random text
> some random text
> test 13.33.55.66
>   description "text17"
> some random text`
> ```

Comment: In the beginning of the indented line - are those spaces or tabs? Python editors tend to substitute tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: Try omitting that last `re.S`. Because _re.S
Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline._ And I think your `.+` is consuming everything.

Comment: Yes I have ommted the `re.S` and still the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure there's a single whitespace character in front of your `description`? Try: `re.findall(r'test\s.+\n\s+description\s"(.+)"', text, re.S)`

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in the regex101 uses tab as separator for `description`, so single `\s` works for it. Replace it with repetition:

```
match = re.findall(r'test\s.+\n\s+description\s\"(.+)\"', text, re.S)
```

Comment: Even with this only last group will be captured because `re.S` will make `.+` consume everything till end.

Comment: The regex is not perfect, I've just pointed topic starter what was wrong. Other improvements, like one you mentioned or removing `.+` definitely could applied.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment try omitting `re.S` because *It makes the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline*

Also `\n\s` is not appropriate. As `\s` includes newline. You will have to use `\s+`

Your regex will be:

```
match = re.findall(r'test\s.+\s+description\s\"(.+)\"', text)
```

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/c68LcR)**